# Appending values as row in R

Tags: r

I have problems to add values to a data frame.
I have three variables that I want them in the end as one row.

```
a <- "aaa"
b <- "bbb"  
c <- [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
```

Now I want to append them as one row, where I would have three columns (each for one of the three variables a,b,c).

```
df <- data.frame()
colnames(df, c("a","b","c"))
df <- ("aaa", "bbb", [1,2,3,4,5,6,7])
```

Is this possible to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A data frame consists of vectors of the same length so you cannot get directly what you are asking with a `data.frame` since the `c` object is itself a vector. There are two possibilities: to recycle the shorter vectors or use a list:

*Recycling:*

```
A <- "aaa"
B <- "bbb"  
C <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)
DF1 <- data.frame(A, B, C)
```

Then `DF1` contains

```
    a   b c
1 aaa bbb 1
2 aaa bbb 2
3 aaa bbb 3
4 aaa bbb 4
5 aaa bbb 5
6 aaa bbb 6
7 aaa bbb 7
```

*Using a list*

```
L <- list(A, B, C)
```

Now `L` contains

```
[[1]]
[1] "aaa"

[[2]]
[1] "bbb"

[[3]]
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
```

and you could iterate over the list using, say, `lapply()` instead of considering it as a row.

Comment: Watch out: in a data.frame columns don’t have to be necessarily vectors. You can have lists too, as the other answers show. A dataframe is in fact a list of vectors or lists with the same length. So, technically, he CAN get what he wants.

Answer (score 3):

With `data.frame`, we can wrap with `list` and use `I` (as is) to create a list column

```
data.frame(A, B, C = I(list(C)))
#    A   B            C
#1 aaa bbb 1, 2, 3,....
```

#### data

```
A <- "aaa"
B <- "bbb"  
C <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you shouldn't do it, but you can do it.

You need `dplyr` version >= 1.0.0
[you can do it even without, but it's cleaner this way]

```
library(dplyr)

# your input
a <- "aaa"
b <- "bbb"  
c <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)

# I assumed your data should be looking like this:
df <- tibble(a = c("zzz", "yyy"),
             b = c("qqq", "www"),
             c = list(c(3,4,5,6,7,8,9),
                      c(2,3,4,5,6,7,8)))

# and this is the new row you want to add
newrow <- tibble(a = a, b = b, c = list(c))

# this is your result
bind_rows(df, newrow)

# # A tibble: 3 x 3
#   a     b     c        
#   <chr> <chr> <list>   
# 1 zzz   qqq   <dbl [7]>
# 2 yyy   www   <dbl [7]>
# 3 aaa   bbb   <dbl [7]>
```

A tibble is a better dataframe.

Note that the last column must be a list, because you want to host a vector of length > 1 in each row for that column.